# Android process not getting removed from "menu button view" when killed

Tags: android, cordova, menu, kill, terminate

Im trying to kill my application, and this also works fine. However when i press the menu key on my nexus 7, the process is still there displaying a black screen. When i click the process it runs app as a from the start, so looks like the kill process works just fine.

This is the method i call on a button click. I want the application to be removed from the menu as well, how do i do that?

```
    public void TerminateAndroid()
{

    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

To your manifest, this will prefend you app being added to the recent apps menu you are talking about.

Note that it will never be added :p

Comment: thx but it doenst work since you cant change manifest file in runtime from false to true.. I need the app to be in most recents when its running.